# Add a class to an html element placed with PHP to finally get the icon

Tags: javascript, php, html, class, addition

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/LaFb9OI1RDfToJqZ?open=lib%2Fscript.js

## Hello

So I try to add   
 class="fas fa-skull-crossbones"  to < i_1 > with javascript. With

```
function crossbones() {
            document.getElementsByName("i_1").classList.add(class="fas fa-skull-crossbones");
```

But it don't works. Final result is to get the icon on each i_1.
 So I am Here to get helps, thanks in advance if you go by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, **[`.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)** targets the `name` attribute; as you're trying to target `<i_1>`, you want **[`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)**.
- Second, `.add(class="fas fa-skull-crossbones"` is invalid; you'll want `.add("fas", "fa-skull-crossbones")`.
- Third, both of these return a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements. You'll need to **loop through** each of these elements, and apply the desired classes to each.
- Finally, you'll want to actually invoke the function `crossbones()`.

This can all be seen in the following:

```js
function crossbones() {
  const elements = document.getElementsByTagName("i_1");
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.add("fas", "fa-skull-crossbones");
  }
}

crossbones();
```

```html
<div_1>
  <p>
    <i_1></i_1> Comment devenir Obèse en 1O leçons
    <i_1></i_1>
    <p>
</div_1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want getElementsByTagName since the markup is going to be <i_1>.  getElementsByName is for elements that have the attribute of name.  Try it out and see if that works.